# NSNotificationCenter observer is not getting removed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I have added `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidLoad` method and removed in `viewDidUnload` but it's not getting removed. I am following ARC. I have followed few answer but I didn't get luck. I dont have reputation for give comments so posting some thing looks like duplicate. Please don't -ve votes.

Sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{     
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self.containerView
                                              selector:@selector(loadInitialScreen)
                                                  name:CLEARSCREEN_DEPOSIT  
                                                object:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.containerView
                                                    name:CLEARSCREEN_DEPOSIT 
                                                  object:nil];

}
```

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but seeing NULL in obj-c is always a red flag

Comment: Are you sure the view is being unloaded?

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the observer either in `-viewWillDisappear:`, `-viewDidDisappear:` or in the `-dealloc` method, depending on your needs. The reason is `-viewDidUnload` in iOS6+ is never called anymore and before iOS6 it's called when a memory warning is received.

Comment: yeah, but i saw some where -dealloc method is not useful when we are using ARC? I will try with viewWillDisappear. Thank you @graver

Comment: `-dealloc` method is totally useful with `ARC`, especially for unregistering observers, releasing C objects, etc. The only thing is that you must not (and actually cannot) is call `[super dealloc];` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `viewDidDisappear` instead `viewDidUnload` :

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.containerView
                                                    name:CLEARSCREEN_DEPOSIT object:nil];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: @trojanfoe check graver's answer. Sorry for late reply I was out for lunch.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidUnload is called (for  < iOS 6.0), when a memory warning is received to the application/view controller.
It will not be called for removal of the view, for that dealloc is called. But as you are using ARC, you cannot implement dealloc method.

The best bet is to remove the observer in the method `loadInitialScreen`, if it has to be called only once.

If your notification can be posted multiple times, it's better to remove the observer in viewDidDisappear, but then add observer for the notification in ViewWillAppear